# While adding AdView in xml error is coming as Class referenced in the layout file, com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView, was not found in the project

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, adview

While adding AdView in xml error is coming as. **Class referenced in the layout file, com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView, was not found in the project or the libraries
Cannot resolve class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView**

Can anyone help me on this error. I'm using latest version of Android Studio.

**Project - Build.Gradle**

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Module - Build.Gradle**

```
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.xx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.0.4"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

**Setting.Gradle**

```
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

include ':app'
rootProject.name = "xx"
```

Answer (score 0):

By tugging the Gradle my issue resolved after 8 days.

[image]